# How to make blocking AWS CLI calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

Most of the AWS CLI calls are asynchronous.

Therefore, after you call them, you have no idea if end product was successful or not.

Is there a simple solution for, checking if environment was created successfully, as an example, other than creating timed polling verification calls, etc etc.

Sorry I did not mention previously, but I am specifically looking for solutions from Powershell

Comment: Are you using aws-cli or aws powershell module?

Comment: I am using aws cli

Comment: Consider working with  aws powershell module, I find it easier and more powershell like

Comment: There are waiter resources available for a few APIs. Let's you created an EC2 instance, by using waiter, we can wait for the EC2 instance to get created. It checks the status of the instance, if it is still creating, sleeps for 10 seconds and checks status again. If (I think) after 60 attempts, instance is not created, it raises an exception and exits.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 can you share a sample? I've been searching about this for a long time. ended up writing my own "waiter" as you can see below.

Comment: Waiting for an ec2 instance to be in running state: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-running.html. Please note: not all services and API operations support waiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check the Exit Status](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-exit-code-of-command) for cli command.

**What is an exit code in bash shell?**

> Every Linux or Unix command executed by the shell script or user has
>   an exit status. Exit status is an integer number. 0 exit status means
>   the command was successful without any errors

code snippet:

```
  aws cli command 

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then 
        echo "Error"
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "Passed"
    fi
```

another method is to wait for a response from the command :

```
while :
do
   sleep 10
   echo "Waiting for elasticsearch domain endpoint..."

   local ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT=$(aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name ${ES_DOMAIN_NAME} --region ${AWS_REGION} --output text --query  'DomainStatus.Endpoints.vpc')

   if [ ${ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT} != "null" ]
   then
      echo "Elasticsearch endpoint: ${ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT}"
      break
   fi
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't  your second example loop forever is something went wrong with deployment?

Comment: No, I first run the command to create the instance and this command is just describe