# Make AWS CLI blocking during cloudfront invalidation creation

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to bust my cloudfront cache during a CI job and then run an Algolia search crawler against the busted version:

```sh
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
```

However, this will basically return a status response with an assigned ID I can poll, which is something I would like to avoid.

The question therefore is, whether this command can be made blocking (could not find anything in the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html)). I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610529/how-to-make-blocking-aws-cli-calls), but is not applicable since my command always exits with 0 exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

What you can do is call the get-invalidation method in a loop (with a sleep in it), and only continue when the status is marked as COMPLETED

See [The CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-invalidation.html)